# Bootstrap 3 collapsed menu flashes down on desktop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 navbar. Everything works fine on mobile but at desktop size the "mobile" collapse version of the navbar flickers down when a nav link is clicked. I just don't want to be able to see this on the desktop.

[You can view a bootply here.](http://www.bootply.com/0vSjsWC9W7)

I am fairly new to web development so I apologize if my code is unorganized or sloppy. The code is...

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.navbar {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .navbar-logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
 }

 .navbar-social {
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .navbar-social i {
  float: left;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #707070;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #909090;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 .navbar-social > p {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  color:#FF344E;
 }


 .navbar .nav-pills>.active>a:hover,.navbar .nav-pills>li>a:hover, .navbar .nav-pills>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.active>a,.navbar .nav-pills>.open>a,.navbar .nav-pills>.open>a, .navbar .nav-pills>.open>a:hover,.navbar .nav-pills>.open>a, .navbar .nav-pills>.open>a:hover, .navbar .nav-pills>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-image: none;
 }

 .navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000;
 }

 .navbar .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 /* fills in background on hamburger menu */
 .navbar-collapse > ul {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
 }

 /* hamburger menu list */
 .navbar .nav-pills>li {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
 }

 /* hamburger menu list item */
 .navbar .nav-pills>li>a {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills .open .dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar .nav-pills .open .dropdown-menu {
     background-color: #f7f7f7;
     color:#ffffff;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>li>a:hover, .navbar .nav-pills>li>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.active>a,.navbar .nav-pills>.open>a, .navbar .nav-pills>.open>a:hover, .navbar .nav-pills>.open>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.active>a:hover, .navbar .nav-pills>.active>a:focus {
  color: #707070;
  background-color: #f60756;
 }

 .navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #ffffff;
 }

 .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #333333;
 }

 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-top-color: #999999;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-top-color: #999999;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #999999;
 }

 .navbar .nav-pills>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #999999;
 }

 /* hamburger menu colors */
 .navbar .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #f60756; /* Change border color around this buttons */
  background: #f60756; /* Change background for button itself */
 }

 .navbar .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: #ffffff; /* Change color for horizontal lines */
 }

 .navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
     <a href="./" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 navbar-logo">
       <img alt="Brand" src="img/" height="100" width="100">
      </a>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-6 navbar-social">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-lg"></i></a>
       <!--TODO check vimeo for removal
       <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vimeo"></i></a> -->
       <p>555.555.5555</p>
   </div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-8 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 nav navbar-nav nav-pills">
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#whyRadicalNav">Why Radical?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#whyGiraffeNav">Why Giraffe?</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#towerNav">Tower</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#storiesNav">Stories</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#contactNav">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are targeting navbar-collapse every time a link is clicked. Exactly why the navbar is behaving funny:

### [Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/wfgQvTTeZB)

instead of this:

```
<li>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#contactNav">Contact</a>
</li>
```

go for this (do this for all the links):

```
<li>
  <a href="#contactNav">Contact</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#whyRadicalNav">Why Radical?</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#whyGiraffeNav">Why Giraffe?</a>
</li>
```

Comment: @CollinMesser if that fixed your problem, you can mark as answer so people won't come wasting their time trying to answer something already done.

Comment: gotcha, I just had to wait for it to let me.

Comment: But then it doesn't collapse the navbar on mobile when navigation is occurring.